# new at lambda as parameters

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm new at this, can someone show me how this works and what goes in "mycode" in order to call the repository?

```
public class MemberService : ServiceBase<IMemberModel>, IMemberService
{        
    public MemberViewModel GetSingle(Expression<Func<MemberViewModel, bool>> whereCondition)
    {
        mycode     
    }
}

public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereCondition)
    {
       return ObjectSet.Where(whereCondition).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is probably a lambda based on a Member, not a MemberViewModel.  Your method should probably be something like:

```
public MemberViewModel GetSingle( Expression<Func<Member,bool>> whereCondition )
{
    var member = this.MemberRepository.GetSingle( whereCondition );
    if (member != null)
    {
        return new MemberViewModel( member );
       // or however you map from member to its view model
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion make sence, but I'm trying not to make the UI aware of Member, which is in the data layer.

Comment: I think it needs a generic custom class and replace the signature with something like ... MemberViewModel GetSingle(CustomObject where). I'm not sure how to do this, but then the BL layer can convert it and call the repository.

Comment: I'll open a new question on how to do the Custom Class.

Comment: Why would your UI be using this method anyway? Seems more appropriate to a Controller (in an MVC pattern) and translating from a domain model to a view model is a perfectly acceptable in a controller.  If you wanted to avoid even that, you could have an expression provider in your model that translates a given set of conditions into an expression that your Controller could use.

Comment: I should have said the UI project, not the UI itself.